# Was ambition considered a character flaw in medieval times or Renaissance?

Tags: middle-ages, religion, renaissance

In Shakespeare's play "Julius Caesar", ambition is an undesirable trait:
 "*The noble Brutus hath told you Caesar was ambitious. If it were so, it was a grievous fault*".
Was ambition widely considered a flaw or a sin, or is just a poetic licence?

Comment: Usually it depends on the word used. Being "ambitious" and being "stubborn" are almost synonymous, one being positive, the other being negative.

Comment: Brutus was implying that Caesar was ambitious for himself whereas this speech by Mark Anthony was pointing out that he was not purely self-motivated. Its usually the first that is seen as a flaw, more so than the latter. But of course there are many nuances.

Comment: Notwithstanding Shakespeare's authorship, this says more about ancient Rome than it di does about renaissance England. Maybe the opprobrium directed towards powerful commoners like Thomas Cromwell is more relevant?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but I must say that I am not entirely convinced that Shakespeare uses the term "ambiton" with more than one nuance.  From Marc Anthony's speech I get the impression that ambition has only a negative connotation. Marc Anthony always tries to proove that Caesar wasn't ambitious, not that his ambitious was directed towards a greater good. Maybe I should address this question in the English stack exchange.

Comment: @NeMo I am not familiar with the subject you mention, can you please link to a resource?

Comment: I got it from reading Wolf Hall, a work of fiction. Perhaps look into Hillary Mantel's sources.